# How To Transmit Data Between A Webpage And An Android-App

Tags: php, android, mysql, web

I need an approach: My aim is to transmit about every minute a number from an Android-App to Webpage, opened on a Computer. It needs to be fast, the computer just has Firefox installed (I can't install programs) and the devices aren't in the same network (has to be over Internet, not bluetooth or similar).

My current solution is a MySQL-Bridge: The opened Webpage on the computer retrieves data from the SQL-Database, filled by the android device, about every second (dirty solution), the problem is, that I use PHP and a while(true)-loop. The webhoster does not allow to set the time limit and I get after a few seconds an error. I have also tried a socket, but then the page loaded the whole time. Have I made a mistake there?

What approach is the best one for my project?

Thanks

Comment: You may like to have a look at 'rethinkdb' and use it instead of mysql. They probably have inbuilt web-sockets support which can update the webpage.

Comment: Rather than the while loop, you could try setting up a `cron` job. Most webhosts allow this - [here is BlueHost's help](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/411) - and it would get you around the process timeout problem. Furthermore, use PHP's [`sleep(1)`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) rather than a `while(true)`! Note this is getting off-topic for here; follow-up on perhaps https://serverfault.com/, please.

Comment: Oh, and for a quick-and-dirty solution, I personally would use Parse.com and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are right about the execution timeout of your php scripts then are there no options you could do. If not, you could try to run the command [`set_time_limit(0);`](http://php.net/function.set-time-limit), this removes the limit of the script execution. If this works you could try so use a [XMPP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) like protocol. I'm sure there are some ready to use libraries.